# retriving a previous copy of my joomla site . error in sql

Tags: sql, joomla

I am designinig my joomla in localhost . but when I am trying to retrive backup site of joomla I am inserting my previous database into joomla . it gives me the following Error .

sql query:

**Dumping data for table `awmbx_assets`**

```
INSERT INTO `awmbx_assets` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `name`, `title`, `rules`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 97, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":{"6":1},"core.admin":{"8":1},"core.manage":{"7":1},"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}'),
(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 'com_admin', 'com_admin', '{}'),
(3, 1, 3, 6, 1, 'com_banners', 'com_banners', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"6":1},"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":[],"core.edit.state":[]}'),
(4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 'com_cache', 'com_cache', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"7":1}}'),
(5, 1, 9, 10, 1, 'com_checkin', 'com_checkin', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"7":1}}'),
(6, 1, 11, 12, 1, 'com_config', 'com_config', '{}'),
(7, 1, 13, 16, 1, 'com_contact', 'com_contact', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.[...]
```

**SQL Error**

```
#1062 - Duplicata du champ '1' pour la clef 'PRIMARY'
```

What should I be doing now?

Comment: Have you tried emptying the table first?
`TRUNCATE awmbx_assets;`

Answer (score 0):

This error says that there is another record in your `awmbx_assets` table having the same `id` as the `id` of a record you are trying to insert now.

First truncate your existing table. Then run the SQL query to insert your backup site's data.

As a side note, I know you are running this in localhost but in general please refrain from sharing the prefix part of your joomla tables (`awmbx` in this case) as exposing the same may have security implications.